# Get all pipeline Jobs in Jenkins Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to trigger several different pipeline jobs, depending on the input parameters of a Controller Pipeline job.

Within this job I build the names of the other pipelines, I want to trigger from a list, given back from a python script.

```
node {
    stage('Get_Clusters_to_Build') {
        copyArtifacts filter: params.file_name_var_mapping, fingerprintArtifacts: true, projectName: 'UpdateConfig', selector: lastSuccessful()
        script {
            cmd_string = 'determine_ci_builds --jobname ' + env.JOB_NAME
            clusters = bat(script: cmd_string, returnStdout: true)
            output_array = clusters.split('\n')
            cluster_array = output_array[2].split(',')
        }
        echo "${clusters}"
    }

    jobs = Hudson.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class)

    echo "$jobs"
    def builders = [:]
    for (i=0; i<cluster_array.size(); i++) {
        def cluster = cluster_array[i]
        def job_to_build = "BuildCI_${cluster}".trim()
        echo "### branch${i}"
        echo "### ${job_to_build}"
        builders["${job_to_build}"] =
        {
            stage("${job_to_build}") {
                build "${job_to_build}"
            }
        }
    }
    parallel builders

    stage ("TriggerTests") {
        echo "Done"   
    }
}
```

My problem is, it might be the case, that a couple of jobs with the names I get from the Stage `Get_Clusters_to_Build` do not exist. Therefore they cannot be triggered and my job fails.

Now to my question, is there a way to get the names of all pipeline jobs, and how can I use them to check if I can trigger a build?

I tried by `jobs = Hudson.instance.getAllItems(AbstractProject.class)` but this gives me only the "normal" FreeStyleProject-Jobs.

I want to do something like this in the loop:

```
def builders = [:]
for (i=0; i<cluster_array.size(); i++) {
    def cluster = cluster_array[i]
    def job_to_build = "BuildCI_${cluster}".trim()
    echo "### branch${i}"
    echo "### ${job_to_build}"

    // This part I only want to be executed if job_to_build is found in the jobs list, somehow like:
    if job_to_build in jobs: // I know, this is not proper groovy syntax
        builders["${job_to_build}"] =
        {
            stage("${job_to_build}") {
                build "${job_to_build}"
            }
        }
}
parallel builders
```

Comment: You could surround possible failing blocks with `try/catch` to handle error cases. The job type is [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-job-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.java).

Comment: If you know the name of the ´job_to_build´ did you try ´Hudson.instance.getItemByFullName(job_to_build)´? That should return null if there's no such item and thus allow you to skip that job gracefully...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All pipeline jobs are instantces of `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob`. So you can get names of all Pipeline jobs using the following function

```
@NonCPS
def getPipelineJobNames() {
    Hudson.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob)*.fullName 
}
```

Then you can use it this way

```
//...
def jobs = getPipelineJobNames()
if (job_to_build in jobs) {
    //....
}
```

Comment: Is there a built-in command to get the pipeline jobs that are in a certain folder ONLY? I know I can write code to filter them.

Answer (score 7):

try this syntax  to get standard and pipeline jobs:

```
def jobs = Hudson.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.Job.class)
```

Answer (score 5):

As @Vitalii Vitrenko wrote, that is working fine

```
for (job in Hudson.instance.getAllItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob)) {
    println job.fullName
}
```

Comment: Note that in your example `job` variable should be an instance of `WorkflowJob`. In OP example `job` is a `String`

Comment: There I receive ``org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.model.ItemGroup getAllItems java.lang.Class``

Comment: Found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940699/get-all-pipeline-jobs-in-jenkins-groovy-script

Comment: @FlorianStraub yes, basically `instance.getAllItems` is accessible for jenkins admins only, otherwise your script needs to be approved within the script approval by jenkins admin within the global configuration